# Default header for Access reports

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to set a default header style which automatically pops up when you run a report in Access? I'd like to have every report have the same header (style) with a logo and the same font used for the title.

Is that possible, because I can't find it.

Comment: Yes, you can put code in the _OnOpen_ event that sets up the header as you like.

Comment: I'm still getting to understand the conventions of Stackoverflow so forgive me but I'm curious as to why this question is off topic. Is it because it's more generally about "how to use" Access as opposed to "how to program/software engineer" using Access? Where is the line drawn? Personally I think the question is a good one and the answer is a clever solution.

Comment: @andrew: SO is about _coding_: [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Gustav - fair enough; understood.

Comment: I agree. With an understanding of the rules, I should have posted this question in Super User. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a subreport for this.

Create an unbound report with the elements you want, and the appropriate height.

Put it as subreport into the header sections of all reports.

Done. And if you need to change anything later (e.g. an address), you only need to change it in one place.

Comment: And to make it easier, create a report with the sub-report in the header, and any common things you like in your reports (such as footers, page setup, etc) and use it as a template for future reports by copying and pasting.